# Tortoise SVN Commit/update Hangs

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, tortoisesvn, svn-update, svncommit

I am having some problems with Tortoise SVN, when I do commit/Update in the project folder, it hangs. I tried to uninstall it and install it again.it did not work. also I tried to downgrade to lower version 1.7.11. It doesnt allow me to update/commit on the project saying, I will need to download latest version
The cleanup Command does work !

Also I tried doing commit changes from Intellij, by right clicking on the file, it gives me an error 
Commit failed with error: 
Cannot run program "svn": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Can someone please help me resolve this? Is there any way around?
It was in working status until last week!! It is giving this problem suddenly.

The version of Tortoise svn
TortoiseSVN 1.8.10, Build 26129 - 64 Bit , 2014/12/17 19:35:51
Subversion 1.8.11, -release
apr 1.5.1
apr-util 1.5.4
serf 1.3.8
OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
zlib 1.2.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable or uncheck the "Use command-line client" option from Subversion settings. It shall fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks! But I have that unchecked already. Still it has the CreateProcess error=2 error

Comment: oh ok, then Install svn command line client. As on windows default selections for installation of TortoisSVN do not include the command line client.

Comment: Sorry this has not yet solved my problem. I get Unexpected HTTP status 400 'Bad Request' on
 '/svn.../svn/.../../../../../.... when I try to update the project using SVN update

Comment: Oh.. then your firewall may be not allowing you to connect. Check with your administrator or use https to connect.

Comment: The answer eventually has led me to simply trying out similar contemporary configurations settings in my IDEA 2021.1 running on a CentOS 8 Linux.
The exact option (a checkbox) I checked to solve the same problem on my side was: Settings -> Version Control -> Subversion -> Enable interactive mode .
Also I checked: 'Use custom configuration directory' checkbox
to be sure I use certain .subversion directory containing my local Subversion settings like the username to be used etc.